I am using python 3.12 and python 3.10 but python 3.10 not working with MSYS2
I assigned py command for 3.12 and python for 3.10 but in MYSY2 but python command is not working.
I changed .bashrc file using nano ~/.bashrc and added line like export PATH=$PATH:/c/python 3.10.0/python.exe after that used source ~/.bashrc to load file after changes.
after that I tried using python command but it is not working.

I set environment variable path for both python version
py and python both works in command prompt. (for 3.12.4 and 3.10.0 version respectively)

(I installed Anaconda3 today and it installed python 3.12.4, my previous version was 3.12.3
Now whenever I run py command it run 3.12.4 instead of 3.12.3)
I want to use python and py command in MYSY2.
How should I do it ?
